# Working on localhost but not on server?

Tags: sql-server, ajax, jquery

I am using the ajax autocompete to search in the website but there is some problem with it. The problem is that when the trigger is done(change event called) the data is fetched and displayed on localhost while it not working on server.

for test i used the code below -

> echo ("gggg1234");            exit;

but still the same, this is echoed in localhost while in server same no result came out? I don't understand it! is the post ajax is not taking place in the case of server? What may be the problem? I have used the

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

this the ajax api i used to retrieved the data.

```
$.post("regsearch.php", {queryString: ""+value+"",queryString1: ""+marvalue+"",queryStringfage: ""+fage+"",queryStringtage: ""+tage+"",queryStringfromh: ""+fromhvalue+"",queryStringtoh: ""+tohvalue+"",queryStringreg: ""+regvalue+"",queryStringcas: ""+casvalue+"",queryStringocc: ""+occvalue+"",queryStringcon: ""+convalue+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
            $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
        }); 
                                        }
```

Above is the code to send ajax post request to `regsearch.php` and retrieve data from it.

In `regsearch.php` the following code is used -

```
    echo ("above isset");
            if(isset($_POST['queryString1'])||isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
                $queryString1 = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString1']);
                $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
                $queryStringfage = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryStringfage']);
                $queryStringtage = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryStringtage']);
                $queryStringtoh = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryStringtoh']);
                $queryStringfromh = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryStringfromh']);
                $queryStringreg= $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryStringreg']);
                $queryStringocc = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryStringocc']);
                $queryStringcon = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryStringcon']);
                $queryStringcas = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryStringcas']);
                echo ("below isset");
echo $queryString1;
            echo $queryString;
            echo $queryStringfage;
            echo $queryStringtage;
            echo $queryStringocc;
            echo $queryStringtoh;
            echo $queryStringfromh;
            echo $queryStringreg;
```

For the test purpose i had used echo which display `echo ("above isset");` and `echo ("below isset");` is displayed while

```
echo $queryString1;
            echo $queryString;
            echo $queryStringfage;
            echo $queryStringtage;
            echo $queryStringocc;
            echo $queryStringtoh;
            echo $queryStringfromh;
            echo $queryStringreg;
```

is not echoed. Solve my problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the code of your AJAX request.
Do you send the request to 'localhost'?
Due to security reasons, you cannot send AJAX requests to a different server than the page was served from.

Answer (score 2):

try activating ajax on the apache server
http://www.ehow.com/how_8767985_activate-ajax-apache-server.html